# Using Regular Expressions in a Cocoa Application for Mac App Store

Tags: cocoa

I have a lot of problems getting regular expressions working for my simple Cocoa application.  I know that many people use RegexpKit Lite, but because it has an undocumented API call (to use the ICU library), I am pretty sure my app would get rejected when submitted to the Mac App Store (I know others have been rejected for using ICU in the iOS App Store).

My next step was to integrate with the full RegExpKit framework.  While this works without issue in my application, it doesn't work in my unit tests.  I have tried a lot of steps here - but, I still keep getting 'library not loaded' for the framework, even though there is a copy files build phase that puts the framework in the correct place.  In addition, I spent quite a bit of time debugging another issue with the RegExpKit framework (dealing with the restrict qualifiers within the framework).  Long story short - I don't think the RegexpKit framework is a good choice for me.

In reality, I just need a simple solution for regular expressions (speed isn't a primary concern as this will be used sparingly) that can be used within my unit tests.

Ideas?

Comment: I don't think you'll get rejected for using RegexKitLite. I have an app in the Mac App Store that does exactly that (I know, that's no guarantee, but I haven't heard from anyone about problems with this).

Comment: What is this undocumented API call used by RegexKit Lite?

Comment: It links to libicu which is not a public API on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Edited post-NDA]

One option is to wait for Lion and then require it. Then you can use [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/).

Comment: Peter - I do have prerelease access and have searched for this - and can't find it.  Can you let me know a topic to search on, or can you email me a link at david at davidtucker dot net ?

Comment: Search for “regular expression”.